# how can i create a file in Linux, without using any program/command?

Tags: linux

I have a question if I want to create a file without using command or programming?
I know `mkdir hi.txt`, but is there any way to make without using these?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. You say "without using commands or programming", and `mkdir` is technically a program invoked by the CLI.

Comment: Try using touch hi.txt

Answer (score 2):

The `touch PATH` program will create an empty file at the location entered for PATH.

Example: `touch /var/tmp/file.txt` will create an empty file at `/var/tmp/file.txt`

Comment: it is solution, but I asked using no command, touch itself is a command

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a file in Linux, without using any program/command,
you can use `>` this sign 
like `> hi.txt` it will create a file